# datediff greater than

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database that keeps track of network outages and I wanted to run a report that will show me the outages that lasted longer than 30 minutes. I can get it to show me all of the outages but I'm not sure how to get it to show me only the ones greater than 30 minutes. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
  StartTime.EventTime, 
  Nodes.NodeId,
  Nodes.Caption, 
  Nodes.Location,
  StartTime.Message, 
  DATEDIFF(Mi, StartTime.EventTime, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 EventTime 
     FROM Events AS Endtime 
     WHERE EndTime.EventTime > StartTime.EventTime  AND EndTime.EventType = 5
       AND EndTime.NetObjectType = 'N' 
       AND EndTime.NetworkNode = StartTime.NetworkNode 
     ORDER BY EndTime.EventTime)) AS OutageDurationInMinutes
FROM Events StartTime INNER JOIN Nodes ON StartTime.NetworkNode = Nodes.NodeID 
WHERE (StartTime.EventType = 1) 
  AND (StartTime.NetObjectType = 'N') 
  AND eventtime between dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) and getdate()
ORDER BY Nodes.Caption ASC
```

The results I'm getting look like this. I've removed some of the info.

```
Time of Outage      Name    Location Down Event          Outage Duration
8/3/2012 4:14       x       x        Stopped Responding                2
8/4/2012 5:14       x       x        Stopped Responding                 
8/5/2012 4:14       x                Stopped Responding               52
8/6/2012 4:14       x       x        Stopped Responding               20
```

Comment: How do you know when the outage ended?

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN`, you should always deal with ranges in the form of 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive' - This is apparently especially true with the date/time types for SQL Server in particular (given some of the changes when casting).  And presuming that you can't record a _future_ event, you should only need to scan for the lower bound.  Also, what about outages that haven't been resolved yet?

Comment: I'm not concerned if it's a current outage I just need a daily report showing outages in the last 24 hour's and for the past week so this does the trick for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make your query a subquery or CTE:

```
with q as (<your query here without the order by>)
select *
from q
where q.OutageDuragtionInMinutes > 30
order by Caption
```